# Automated file backups/copies that are not symlinks

Tags: rsync, backup, symlink, synchronization

I have 2 directories:

> /home/Documents/oppo/
>
> /home/Backup/oppo/

If I wanted to manually copy the contents over, I would do:

`rsync -av /home/Documents/oppo/ /home/Backup/oppo/`

But I am actually looking for something that is like a symlink but not actually a symlink. Meaning that I want the backup to happen in `/home/Backup/oppo` without needing to run the `rsync` command manually each time.

I know symlinks are not the correct solution because they just point to the original folder, but is there something similar to it that actually preserves a backup automatically?

Also, I can't run a systemd service because this is a VM that I sparsely use.

tl;dr I want the power of symlinks that store actual backup copies of files automatically

Comment: It appears both of these directories on the same Linux machine and on the same filesytem /home?  rsync is a far better solution then symlinks. Use a cron job to run a simple script for launching rsync. Or use the .logout file to execute the  rysnc script when you logout.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run a program to do this, then you prefer to be using a filesystem that manages the copies for you.  Several filesystems have snapshot capabilities that preserve older copies of files.

BTRFS and ZFS are possible to run in ways that support periodic snapshot creation.

> I can't run a systemd service because this is a VM that I sparsely use.

I don't see how that's a huge limitation.  Presumably while the VM is not in use, it's also not manipulating files, so you don't need to copy anything.  When the machine is booted up, the service could see if a backup is necessary and create one.